# JS Accordion Image Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I would like to know how to apply custom, toggling 'plus' and 'minus' icons to this script. The accordion works just fine, but I seem to be stuck there.

```
<!-- JS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

    //Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

    //Hide the other panels
    $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
  });
});
</script>
```

It's probably a simple fix, but my heart lies on the design side of the fence. I would really appreciate whatever help can be provided!

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want to use the jQuery accordion but change the icons to a plus and minus.  You also want the section that is clicked to expand while all the others collapse.  Correct me if I am wrong.

Here is the jQuery page for accordion and custom icons: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#custom-icons

Here is a page that lists the possible icons you could choose from: http://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/jqueryui-icons/

I copied the code from the jQuery page and just changed the icons to be plus and minus, which is this bit:

```
var icons = {
    header: "ui-icon-plus",
    activeHeader: "ui-icon-minus"
};
```

Here is the whole page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Customize icons</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Arial",  "Verdana", "sans-serif";
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
</style>

  <script>
  $(function() {
    var icons = {
      header: "ui-icon-plus",
      activeHeader: "ui-icon-minus"
    };
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      icons: icons
    });
    $( "#toggle" ).button().click(function() {
      if ( $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons" ) ) {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons", null );
      } else {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons", icons );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est. </p><p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="toggle">Toggle icons</button>


</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.